# The use of "very" and "so" in the "that-clause"

Tags: confusable, intensifiers

> 1. I'm **very sorry** that I can't join you.
> 2. I'm **so sorry** that I can't join you.

Which one is grammatical and correct? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Both are fine for me.

Comment: Both are OK. I would say 1. is more formal. 2. adds a bit of emotional involvement.

Comment: "That" looks like an expletive here.

Comment: Can the word "very" be used before the "that-clauses"? Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think either is incorrect, or that the "that-clause" has any special rule for using "so" vs. "that".

I'd say "so sorry" sounds emphatic/emotional. "very sorry" sounds more plain and formal, but maybe more sincere.

Althought the "so" version can be more emotional, in certain contexts it can add a tone of sarcasm, especially if you're appologizing for something minor. I'd avoid this expression unless you think you can convey your tone unambiguously.

I think the most idiomatic expression in American English is "really sorry", but that is casual.

In a more formal situation I'd use no adverb at all, and in very formal situations use "apologize".